# Grouped products - link from associated product name in list to a detailed product page

Tags: product, grouped-products

I am trying to figure out the best way to set up my catalog, but I stumble upon something.
I have to say that I am new to Magento, very willing to learn and eager to start… but not sure how..

Anyway, my question is:

I added a grouped product, CIS-K6, see http://www.etk-mood.nl/shop/catalogus/inbouw/downlighters-led.html

And I added some simple products, *cisk6-2700w* and *cisk6-2700w-nd* as associated products.

But when I click the above link I see this:
http://www.etk-mood.nl/shop/catalogus/inbouw/downlighters-led/cis-k6-900.html 
but what I need is to be able to click on the product name and go to a more detailed product page with a description.

Or perhaps skip the additional page and add a description, a little thumbnail and perhaps something else to the product name list on this page, and display the list under the photo, so I can add more columns.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the associated product names clickable by editing the template file : `/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml` and replace

```
<td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></td>
```

with

```
<td>
   <?php if ($_item->getVisibility() != Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE)) : //if simple product is visible?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl()?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
   <?php else :?>
       <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
   <?php endif;?>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply. It worked after I removed a ) after VISIBLE. However the first column under the header is empty now, productname is under Price. Could you tell me how to change that? I suppose I should learn php, and I will. Anyway, thanks again, I appreciate your fast response.

Comment: @lidacha. Did it work for you?

Comment: I needed to remove the <td> tags. Should have seen that. Now it works perfectly. Thanks again!